# Backbone.js Model.Save resets DOM events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, backbone.js

Consider the following made up example:

```
events: {
  'mouseup #element':  'saveModel',
  'click #button': 'foo'
},
```

Lets assume that **button is located inside #element**.

Now **when I click directly on the button, foo is never executed.** saveModel gets executed normally. **If I do not save the model in saveModel function then foo gets executed.**

Why is that? How to fix this?

**EDIT:**
I added a small demo. It is the todos example from backbon/examples. I just made some small modifications to display the error. To reproduce click on button test and then try to click on todo title and you will see that the event handler for title will not fire.

This is a mediafire link with zipped example. 
http://www.mediafire.com/?uiy3ovwnvkiv1ys

Comment: Can you provide a minimal demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com? What event listeners are there on the model?

Comment: @muistooshort I added a demo.

Comment: I can't check out your demo right now, but I suspect that you are replacing your root element or removing it from the `DOM` so the bound events get lost, try calling [delegate-events](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents) to redelegate your event hash.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think anyone is going to wade through all that or even download and run something from a zip file. If you set up a minimal demo (with emphasis on *minimal*) that is just enough to demonstrate your problem then you'll have better luck. Help us help you.

Comment: I'll try to come up with something more minimal, but when I tried to reproduce it in some other way nothing happened.